# which residual vs fitted plot is looking better here?

Tags: regression, variance, residuals, weighted-regression, leverage

This is a data analysis project we have at school where we try different ways to correct a simple linear regression model. My first attempt is just trying to transform the response variable by taking the square root of it. The second attempt is a weighted least square where the square is 1/fitted^2 where fitted is the previous model fitted value. And I got 2 new residual vs fitted plots. What I want to know is which one look the best?

[image: Simple linear regression]
Simple linear regression

[image: weighted least square]
weighted least square

[image: Y transform]
Y transform

Finally, I also want to ask if I were to found some leverage and influential points what should I do with it.

Comment: how to define "better"? why use eyes instead of a metric, such as MSE?

Comment: I was looking for an answer of something like the second looking like it is fanning out and the third one looks like it doesn't have any sort of pattern what so ever which mean the third one is better. I also want to know what you usually do with leverage and influential points.

Comment: Plotting with the same axis ranges will help you in resolving this question, as comparison is easier when all plots are made at the same scale.